# how to upload a complete directory structure to artifactory using customized property?

Tags: artifactory

How to upload a complete directory structure  to artifactory using customized property?
I have to upload a complete hierarchy structure in Artifactory using customized property

Comment: You should post the code that you have already tried.

Comment: What's "customized property"?

Answer (score 11):

Not sure what "customized property" is, but in general you have 2 options:

1. Upload from server, which is essentially, [repository import](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Importing+and+Exporting#ImportingandExporting-Import). You point Artifactory to a directory on the server and it sucks everything in.
2. Upload from client, which is essentially, [archive deployment](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Deploying+Artifacts). You pack your files in an archive and then deploy. Artifactory will unpack the file to the correct repository, keeping the directory structure.

---

<sup>I am with [JFrog](http://jfrog.com), the company behind [Bintray](https://bintray.com/) and [[artifactory]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/artifactory), see [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402053/jbaruch) for details and links.</sup>

Comment: I uploaded an archive from the client, but it didn't unpack the file like you said it would.  It just uploaded the zip.

Comment: Turns out I had to check a box, something about "bundle"